# Foundation: about source ordering (no flex grid)

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a 3-column grid, with content and a sidebar. On small and medium devices each takes up 12 columns. See [cdpn.io/anon/pen/bqENqG](http://cdpn.io/anon/pen/bqENqG).

I need the sidebar to come **after** articles on small and medium devices like this:

[image]

Or the sidebar and articles can be swapped in the HTML, because the sidebar on the small screen should come last (I'm building this site mobile-first).

I *think* the correct HTML structure to do that would be:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-9 columns" style="background: #B9B9B9;">CONTENT</div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-3 columns" style="background: #919191;">ARTICLES</div>
  <div class="small-12 columns" style="background: #AAA4A4;">SIDERBAR</div>
</div>
```

Using the above code, how would I be able to have `Sidebar` on the right (with `Content` and `Articles` on the left) on a large screen?

Essentially, I want it to look like this:

**Content | Sidebar 

Articles**

Is this possible to do with pull/push in this situation?

I'm using Zurb Foundation, and found [this link](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/grid.html#source-ordering) on source ordering in a grid, which may help.

Please help me, and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use visivilty classes... however, the flexbox was designed perfect for that... check the last example from here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

and also, you don't need the medium-12 class, or the small-12

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="large-9 column" style="background: #B9B9B9;">CONTENT</div>
    <div class="column large-3 show-for-large" style="background: #AAA4A4;">SIDERBAR</div>
      <div class="columns" style="background: #919191;">ARTICLES</div>
      <div class="columns hide-for-large" style="background: #AAA4A4;">SIDERBAR</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hello!

1) I can not use flex (flex grid in foundation) in my current project -)

2) Hmmm. No. You use 2 elements SIDEBAR in HTML markup, It is not right (Double content). MY SIDEBAR div contains many nested elements (forms, banners and other blocks), so anyway it is unrealistic repeat html code

Comment: You can use javascript?

Comment: I think yes, but in this case I would have solved the problem myself. Anyway, your solution to the problem?

Comment: In your case, javascript that's all that I think it's exist, there is position relative but only if you know the height of article/sidebar ( This is like fundation ordering, they know the width in percentages )

Comment: Ohh, you said you know how to resove this with javascript :))

Comment: Interesting your example, Brada

Comment: Thank you, did you saw how smooth the transition is? :D

Comment: Sorry Brada, I do not understand what you mean. "transition"? Where, what about you?

Comment: Noooo, you don't understand what I mean, right? sure thing :)) But it's good that I understand you.